# same network structure, same data, same optimizer, same loss function, but different val_dice_coe between keras and tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, image-segmentation

I build a 'unet' to do image segmentation by keras, then train the network through 'fit_generator', and I got dice_coe by 0.91 on validation data and 0.92 on training data, however, when training the same 'unet'(code to build the network doesn't change) by tensorflow, overfitting is really serious. so how can i get a same result through tensorflow and keras

Comment: Make sure the variables are initialized the same way, and that the network sees the data in the same order. You can do this by [setting the random seed](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed)

Comment: Please provide your code. Keras does a lot what you have to write in tensorflow manually. E.g. the dataset will be shuffled after each epoch, so every epoch gets different batches.

Comment: I have figured it out what is going on, I tested it with a different batchsize, so the network's performence is not stable because of batchnormation